# Installing software for bioinformatics

Tags: software-installation

I'm totally new to Linux, got it because some programs i need for bioinformatics research either work only on linux or are easily operated from linux.

At the moment trying to install a program called Mothur. Following installation pipeline for linux/unix https://www.mothur.org/wiki/Installation:

1) downloaded the program
2) went through these steps:

```
mkdir mothur
cd mothur
unzip ../Mothur.source.zip
make
```

the error I get says:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I have no idea what this means.

Further in the tutorial it says:

> To run mothur:
>
> ```
> ./mothur
> ```
>
> Hopefully, mothur will open in the interactive mode.

It doesn't.

Would be really grateful for some help.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick check and it seams that the package you are looking for is available in the existing software selection.

To install open terminal and type

```
Sudo apt install mothur
```

This should install the program you are looking for 
You will then be able to find it in the applications installed on your system.

This is better then trying to use, make, if you are unfamiliar with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you reversed the order of two commands in the installation instructions. It should be:

```
unzip mothur.zip
cd mothur
make
```

The `Makefile` used by `make` to build the program from source is inside a subdirectory `motur` of the source code archive. If you invoke `make` without telling it where to look for a `Makefile` it will only look for it in the current working directory. (Short of that it uses its built-in build rule set which doesn't include a default target rule to use when none is specified.)

All that is notwithstanding that you can install Mothur from Ubuntu's package repository:

```
sudo apt install mothur
```

Answer (score 0):

"`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`" means that there is no makefile (containing rules to let `make` build your software) in the current directory. After your `cd mothur`, use `ls` to see which files and directories got unpacked. There will probably be a directory called `build`, `source`, or even `src`. Search the for a file called 'Makefile', `cd` to that directory and retry the `make`.